# Algebra II online courses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Can anyone give me recommendations for Algebra II online courses. I do know about Khan academy but looking for other courses that are also really good for learning Algebra II.

Thank you

Comment: What do you call "Algebra II" to? For high school, college, Mathematics department...? In what school, university...? Better, find out what the syllabus of that course is.

Comment: You might look at https://artofproblemsolving.com/school/catalog and see "Intro to Algebra B."

Comment: @DonAntonio I searched for "Khan academy" and found the course named [Algebra II](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2). Seems to be high school level.

Answer (score 1):

Try these courses:

1. https://brilliant.org/courses/graphing-and-modeling/landing/?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=search&utm_term=%2Balgebra%20%2B2%20%2Bcourse_&utm_content=486381395220_&utm_campaign=11315342810_consolidated_sem&gclid=CjwKCAiAgc-ABhA7EiwAjev-jy3fNTwe-Bw0QmyYiSr8R0j5_7_KxtKh5AyamzQMS87Z2Bl6FoVasRoCkpYQAvD_BwE
2. https://www.thegreatcoursesplus.com/algebra-ii
3. https://www.udemy.com/course/algebra2-course/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=LongTail_la.EN_cc.US&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_81829991947_._ad_436603485109_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_dsa-1007766171592_._li_9053025_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=CjwKCAiAgc-ABhA7EiwAjev-j91v0deqTa2fiPjOlRhYfyhuDWwWuluPjzHQore8SH2VbSbA5DwL1BoChMYQAvD_BwE

Brilliant.org and Udemy are highly reputable. While the great course plus has a free trial.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about edX?

They have thousands of courses on virtually every subject you could ever want.